# How do i convert duration column into hours and minutes?

Tags: python, time, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm currently sitting in Jupyter Notebook on a dataset that has a duration column that looks like this;

[image]

I still feel like a newbie at programming at programming, so i'm not sure to convert this data so it can be visualized in graphs in jupyter. Right now its just all strings in the column.
Does anyone knows how i do this right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each time in your data is a string and assuming the formats are all as shown then you could use a parser after a little massaging of the data:

```
from dateutil import parser

s = "1 hour 35 mins"
print(s)

s = s.replace('min', 'minute')
time = parser.parse(s).time()
print(time)
```

This somewhat less flexible than the answer from @Jimpsoni which captures the two numbers but will work on your data and variations such as "1h 35m". If your data is in a List then you can loop through it; if in a Pandas series then you could form a function and use .apply to convert the values in the series.

Comment: My solution also works with any variation since regex is just extracting all the numbers from the string, but this one looks neater and uses less libraries than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through your dataset and extract the numbers from the strings and then turn those numbers into timedelta objects. Here is a one example from your dataset.

```
from datetime import timedelta
import re

string = "1 hour 35 mins"  # Example from dataset

# Extract numbers with regex
numbers = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', string)))  

# Create timedelta object from those numbers
if len(numbers) < 2:
  time = timedelta(minutes=numbers[0])
else:
  time = timedelta(hours=numbers[0], minutes=numbers[1])

print(time) # -> prints 1:35:00
```

More about deltatime object [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

What is the optimal way to loop through your dataset really depends in what form is your data in but this is an example how you would do it to one instance of data.